# UIActivityViewController equivalent on ios 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share some text from an application. If the user has ios 6 installed I will call UIActivityViewController to share. However if the user has ios 5 is there anything similar i can call that would have buttons to share to mail and twitter....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. The easiest way is to use a `UIActionSheet` with buttons for each service you need, and then call through to the various APIs as required.

Answer (score 6):

use OWActivityViewController instead UIActivityViewController in ios 5 you can check it [Here](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController)