# UIActivityViewController for older iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIActivityViewController equivalent on ios 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142446/uiactivityviewcontroller-equivalent-on-ios-5)

Is there an alternative for `UIActivityViewController` for iOS 5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. What I would suggest is to make a custom `UIActionSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested mainly in the sharing aspects, I'd suggest taking a look at [Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/). For other functionality, you'll need to create your own UIActionSheet or other popup control. The UIActivityViewController is the iOS6 answer to rolling your own.